# Is it good to insert database access dependency in an abstract factory?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, abstract-factory

I am having an abstract factory class StudentValidatorFactory which is suppossed to create(based on a specified parameter) various StudentValidator class instances to which a validation map has to be injected (see the code bellow).

```
public class StudentValidatorFactory{
    public static final int JUNIOR_STUDENT_TYPE = 1;

    public static final int SENIOR_STUDENT_TYPE = 2;

    public StudentValidator createStudentValidator(int studentType) throws StudentValidatorCreationException{
            Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap = readValiationMapFromPersistentOrCachedStorage(studentType);
            switch (studentType){
                  case JUNIOR_STUDENT:
                      return new JuniorStudentValidator(validationMap);
                  case SENIOR_STUDENT:
                      return new SeniorStudentValidator(validationMap);
            }  
    }
}

public interface StudentValidator{
      void validate(Student student) throws StudentValidationException;
}


public class JuniorStudentValidator{
     private Map<String, ValidationBean> validationMap;           

     public JuniorStudentValidator(Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap){
         this.validationMap = validationMap;
     }

     public void validate(Student student) throws StudentValidationException{
         // make use of validation map for apply junior student related validations on the student
     } 

}


public class SeniorStudentValidator{
     private Map<String, ValidationBean> validationMap;           

     public SeniorStudentValidator(Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap){
         this.validationMap = validationMap;
     }


     public void validate(Student student) throws StudentValidationException{
         // make use of validation map for apply senior student related validations on the student
     } 

}
```

My question is about the **StudentValidatorFactory.createStudentValidator(int studentType)** method whether reading the validation map from a persistent storage (based on the student type) should be done within the create method ? Otherwise said, should the factory be aware/dependent about such implementation details?

I'd appreciate if there would be a solution to avoid the switch(studentType) statement when creating the student validator - an idea on top of my head is to have an internally managed map  and perform the StudentValidator concrete class instantiation via reflection .

Advantages of using such a technique is that the validators are much easier to be tested (through dependency injection).

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `readValiationMapFromPersistentOrCachedStorage(studentType)` in a separated service interface `StudentValidatorService` and inject an instance of the service in the `StudentValidatorFactory` using a property or constructor argument:

```
public interface StudentValidatorService {
    Map<String,ValidationBean> getValidationMap(int studentType);
}

public class StudentValidatorFactory{
    public static final int JUNIOR_STUDENT_TYPE = 1;

    public static final int SENIOR_STUDENT_TYPE = 2;

    public StudentValidatorFactory(StudentValidatorService studentValidatorService) {
        this.studentValidatorService = studentValidatorService;
    }

    public StudentValidator createStudentValidator(int studentType) throws StudentValidatorCreationException{
            Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap = studentValidatorService.getValidationMap(studentType);
            switch (studentType){
                  case JUNIOR_STUDENT:
                      return new JuniorStudentValidator(validationMap);
                  case SENIOR_STUDENT:
                      return new SeniorStudentValidator(validationMap);
            }  
    }
}
```

Now you can write an implementation of `StudentValidatorService` backed by database. Or you can write a mock implementation for testing. The implementation is now decoupled from the usage.

---

To remove the switch-case, invert it using an enum:

```
public enum StudentType {
    JUNIOR_STUDENT {
        public StudentValidator getValidator(Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap) {
            return new JuniorStudentValidator(validationMap);
        }
    },
    SENIOR_STUDENT {
        public StudentValidator getValidator(Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap) {
            return new SeniorStudentValidator(validationMap);
        }
    };

    public abstract StudentValidator getValidator(Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap);
}

public class StudentValidatorFactory{

    public StudentValidatorFactory(StudentValidatorService studentValidatorService) {
        this.studentValidatorService = studentValidatorService;
    }

    public StudentValidator createStudentValidator(StudentType studentType) throws StudentValidatorCreationException{
            Map<String,ValidationBean> validationMap = studentValidatorService.getValidationMap(studentType);
            return studentType.getValidator(validationMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an improvement for the provided code, but it doesn't answer the question. Is a dependency on the factory for the student validation retrieval necessary, or is there a better solution available by avoiding the **switch** for the student type? I am searching for a manner to implement the presented functionality more loosely coupled.

Comment: @marius_neo: You did not mention 'switch statement issue' in your question.